# awk to extract lines in file that contain matching pattern and variable digit

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to use `awk` to extract those lines that in `$2` contain `exon (some digit that is 1-99) sequence`. The text will always be the same but the digit will be variable.

**file** `tab-delimeted`

```
Tier 2  exon 10 sequence    xxxxx
Tier 2  full sequence   yyyyy
Tier 1  exon 5 sequence aaaaa
```

**desired output** `tab-delimeted`

```
Tier 2  exon 10 sequence    xxxxx
Tier 1  exon 5 sequence aaaaa
```

**awk**

```
 awk '$2 ~ /^exon [0-9][0-9] sequence$/' file
```

Comment: Maybe `awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; $2~/^exon [0-9]{1,2} sequence$/' file` ?

Comment: you need to print something in awk, right : `'{pritn $0}'`; but why awk at all? you just need `grep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' '$2 ~ /exon [1-9][0-9]? sequence/' file
```

Note that the regexp for `1-99` is `[1-9][0-9]?`, not `[0-9][0-9]?` as that latter would include `0` (as well as `00`, `01`, etc.).

Comment: Note that `/exon [1-9][0-9]? sequence/` won't match if the lines contains an extra space in the place of the leading `[1-9]`  Common to print nums right justified. The OP does not show it that way, but it is common.

Comment: Yup, there's a lot about this question and answer that could be improved on - I highly doubt that this regexp comparison is the best way to do whatever the OP is really trying to do which is why I'm not putting much effort into the answer and instead just giving the OP what she asked for.

Answer (score 3):

using awk

```
awk   '/exon\s+[0-9]+\s+sequence/  {print $0}'  file
```

or grep

```
 grep -P 'exon\s+[0-9]+\s+sequence' file
```

Comment: printing the current record is what awk does by default given a true condition (e.g. a regexp comparison match), you don't need to add an explicit `{print $0}` statement. You should mention your solutions are both GNU-specific though and the grep one relies on "highly experimental" functionality per the GNU grep man page.

Comment: This is not specific to column 2

Comment: there is not much specific about col 2 in the examples. But if this is important, the regex should be changed to something like the following `^[^\s]+\s+exon\s+[0-9]+\s+\sequence`. Also note, that `\s` covers all space chars, not just tabs. So, if there are spaces involved in the parts, then yes, the tab should be used int the  regex. This requirement is not obvious from the examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="|"} $1=$1' file 
Tier 2|exon 10 sequence|xxxxx
Tier 2|full sequence|yyyyy
Tier 1|exon 5 sequence|aaaaa
```

(i.e., the tabs are where the `|` are above)

You can do:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '$2~/exon[ ]+[0-9][0-9]?/' /tmp/file 
Tier 2  exon 10 sequence    xxxxx
Tier 1  exon 5 sequence aaaaa
```

Comment: @EdMorton: Yup. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you all :).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$3 ~ /exon/' file

Tier 2  exon 10 sequence    xxxxx
Tier 1  exon 5 sequence aaaaa
```